# Hmac MD5 of a large file

Tags: java, hmac, javax.crypto

I'm using FileInputStream wrapped with BufferedInputStream for reading in a large file in byte chunks.

```
public void MD5(BufferedInputStream in, Key pubKey) throws Exception{

        Mac md = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
            md.init(pubKey);
            byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
            int readSize;
            while ((readSize = in.read(contents)) != -1) {
                {
                    md.update(contents,0,readSize);
                }
                byte[] hashValue = md.doFinal();

            }
}
```

It works perfectly fine for a small file, but takes **insane amounts of time** for a  file 200MB file.

The same approach works perfectly fine while I try to sign the 200MB file using SHA256withRSA.

Is there any specific reason for this?? I have a feeling it is something to do with **md.update().**

But I've used the same function while using 'Signature' as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could add log to check what is taking insane amount of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `doFinal` within the while-loop. That doesn't look right. Try the following:

```
public void MD5(BufferedInputStream in, Key pubKey) throws Exception{
    Mac md = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
    md.init(pubKey);
    byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
    int readSize;
    while ((readSize = in.read(contents)) != -1) {
        md.update(contents, 0, readSize);
    }
    byte[] hashValue = md.doFinal();
}
```

Comment: He would also do well to use a much bigger buffer, say 8k or 32k.